# RestrictionsManager not able to get policy managed configurations in Android

Tags: android, mdm, android-management-api, android-work-profile

While creating a managed device, we are sending some data in key-value pairs using managedConfiguration while creating a policy.

While creating a policy for fully-managed device then we are getting the data using the restrictionsManager inside a custom managed application that is marked as required for setup.

We're able to get the data like in the app like this as per the official documentation:

```
val restrictionManager = getSystemService(Context.RESTRICTIONS_SERVICE) as RestrictionsManager
val appRestrictions = restrictionManager.applicationRestrictions

if (appRestrictions != null){
    val toId = appRestrictions.getString(AppDataStoreKey.ToId.key)
    val link = appRestrictions.getString(AppDataStoreKey.Link.key)
    val userName = appRestrictions.getString(AppDataStoreKey.UserName.key)

    Log.d(TAG, "onCreate: Restrictions Data: \nToID: $toId \nLink: $link \nUserName: $userName")
}
```

But while creating a policy for work-profile then the above snippet returns null values while extracting the data using the keys.
Additionally, if we update the same data with any change in the **managedConfigurations** then the restrictions manager broadcast receiver gets the data and closing and re-opening the app now works as expected.

So we face this issue in the work-profile for the first time trying to get the managed configuration data.

Why is that and how to resolve it.

Comment: Maybe the app in work-profile case is opening in private space not in the work container?

Comment: I tried openning the app even after work profile setup, the app doesn't get any data, still null.